# How to determine time for a point of mass to reach another point

Tags: newtonian-mechanics

How can I determine the time it takes for a point of mass due to the $F_{x} = y$, $F_{y} = x$ force where $m = 1$ to reach the point $B \left( 2, 2 \right)$ from point $A \left( 1, 1 \right)$ at the initial velocity $v_{0} = \left( 1, 1 \right)$?

Comment: As it is defined, it seems that your given force declarations very much resembles a chaotic attractor system, where solution of differential equations is too much sensitive on starting conditions (coordinates and initial forces). If you change them a bit,- outcome will be completely different, so in general if you have such chaotic system of inter-dependent forces, no clear solution exists.

Answer (score 1):

Hi Angry the answer to this is essentially the same as to the last question you asked. You can again solve the differential equation of the particle to find the path this particle will take. If you have that just solve the equation
$\vec{x}(t) = \vec{B}$  where you plug in the explicit solution for $\vec{x}(t)$ that you calculated by solving the differential equation. Now just solve for $t$.